# Распарсить словарь из колонки в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dict, type-error

У меня трудности при получение данных из колонки, которая представлена в виде словаря.

Имеется колонка `df['analytic']`:

```
1    {'name': 'Elena', 'id': '5cb440c999bdd22a80189...
2    {'name': 'Elena', 'id': '5cb440c999bdd22a80189...
3    {'name': 'Georgy.Tskhadadze', 'id': '5cb9b02b5...
4    {'name': 'Georgy.Tskhadadze', 'id': '5c
```

Пытаюсь из колонки забрать только 'name' с помощь кода:

```
df['newcolumn'] = df['analytic'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> ```
> TypeError:'float' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, в некоторых ячейках у вас не словарь, а значение типа `float` или `NaN`.

Попробуйте так:

Исходный DF:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:   "analytic":[{'name': 'Elena', 'id':1}, {'name': 'Georgy', 'id':2}, np.nan, None, 1.23]
   ...: })

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
                      analytic
0   {'name': 'Elena', 'id': 1}
1  {'name': 'Georgy', 'id': 2}
2                          NaN
3                         None
4                         1.23
```

создаем новый столбец:

```
In [6]: df["new"] = (df["analytic"]
                     .apply(lambda x: x.get("name") 
                                      if isinstance(x, dict) 
                                      else np.nan))
```

результат:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
                      analytic     new
0   {'name': 'Elena', 'id': 1}   Elena
1  {'name': 'Georgy', 'id': 2}  Georgy
2                          NaN     NaN
3                         None     NaN
4                         1.23     NaN
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!